# Mocking a void method in the Spring Framework (Mockito)

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm writing integration tests for a spring web app and I have reached a step where I need to mock service methods calls which have a void return type. I've done some research on some ways to do this but none seem to be the correct way.

What I want to do is:

- When the save() method is called on recipeService, it should save the recipe

Below I'll provide the code and also the two main ways I've tried already. If anyone can help that would be great!

**The method that needs mocking**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/recipes/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String persistRecipe(@Valid Recipe recipe, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile photo, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("recipe", recipe);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash",
                new FlashMessage("I think you missed something. Try again!", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
        return "redirect:/recipes/add";
    }

    User user = getUser();
    recipe.setOwner(user);
    user.addFavorite(recipe);
    recipeService.save(recipe, photo);
    userService.save(user);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("The recipe has successfully been created", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));

    return "redirect:/recipes";
}
```

**The service that needs calling (save method)**

```
@Service
public class RecipeServiceImpl implements RecipeService {

private final RecipeRepository recipes;

@Autowired
public RecipeServiceImpl(RecipeRepository recipes) {
    this.recipes = recipes;
}

@Override
public void save(Recipe recipe, byte[] photo) {
    recipe.setPhoto(photo);
    recipes.save(recipe);
}

@Override
public void save(Recipe recipe, MultipartFile photo) {
    try {
        recipe.setPhoto(photo.getBytes());
        recipes.save(recipe);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public Recipe findById(Long id) {
    Optional<Recipe> recipe = recipes.findById(id);
    if (recipe.isPresent()) {
        return recipe.get();
    }

    // TODO:drt - Create new exception to handle this
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

@Override
public Recipe findByName(String name) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Recipe> findAll() {
    return (List<Recipe>) recipes.findAll();
}

@Override
public void deleteById(Long id) {
    recipes.deleteById(id);
}
```

}

**Attempt 1**

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(value = "daniel")
public void createNewRecipeRedirects() throws Exception {
    User user = userBuilder();
    Recipe recipe = recipeBuilder(1L);
    recipe.setOwner(user);
    user.addFavorite(recipe);
    MockMultipartFile photo = new MockMultipartFile("image", "food.jpeg",
                    "image/png", "test image".getBytes());

    when(userService.findByUsername("daniel")).thenReturn(user);

    doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
            if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 1 && arguments[0] != null && arguments[1] != null) {

                Recipe recipe1 = (Recipe) arguments[0];
                MultipartFile file = (MultipartFile) arguments[1];
                recipe1.setPhoto(file.getBytes());

            }
            return null;
        }
    }).when(recipeService).save(any(Recipe.class), any(MultipartFile.class));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes/add"))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/recipes"))
            .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("flash"));


}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(value = "daniel")
public void createNewRecipeRedirects() throws Exception {
    List<Recipe> recipes = recipeListBuilder();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    User user = userBuilder();
    Recipe recipe = recipeBuilder(1L);
    recipe.setOwner(user);
    user.addFavorite(recipe);
    MockMultipartFile photo = new MockMultipartFile("image", "food.jpeg",
                    "image/png", "test image".getBytes());

    when(userService.findByUsername("daniel")).thenReturn(user);

    doAnswer(answer -> {
        recipe.setPhoto(photo.getBytes());
        recipes.add(recipe);
        return true;
    }).when(recipeService).save(any(Recipe.class), any(MultipartFile.class));

    doAnswer(answer -> {
        users.add(user);
        return true;
    }).when(userService).save(any(User.class));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes/add"))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/recipes"))
            .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("flash"));

    assertEquals(3, recipes.size());
    assertEquals(1, users.size());
}
```

**Complete test code so far**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class RecipeControllerTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private RecipeService recipeService;

@Mock
private UserService userService;

@Mock
private IngredientService ingredientService;

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext wac;

@InjectMocks
private RecipeController recipeController;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).apply(springSecurity()).build();
}

/**
 * Tests for index pages / & /recipes
 */
@Test
@WithUserDetails(value = "daniel")
public void indexPageLoads() throws Exception {
    List<Recipe> recipes = recipeListBuilder();
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = ingredientsListBuilder();

    when(recipeService.findAll()).thenReturn(recipes);
    when(ingredientService.findAll()).thenReturn(ingredients);
    when(userService.findByUsername("daniel")).thenReturn(userBuilder());

    mockMvc.perform(get("/recipes"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("recipes", "ingredients", "favs"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

/**
 * Tests for page /recipes/add
 */
@Test
@WithMockUser
public void addRecipePageLoads() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/recipes/add"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("task", "buttonAction", "action", "photo", "recipe"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

@Test
@WithUserDetails("daniel")
public void createNewRecipeRedirects() throws Exception {
    User user = userBuilder();
    Recipe recipe = recipeBuilder(1L);
    recipe.setOwner(user);
    user.addFavorite(recipe);
    MultipartFile photo = new MockMultipartFile("image", "food.jpeg",
            "image/jpeg", "dummy content file".getBytes());

    when(userService.findByUsername("daniel")).thenReturn(user);
    verify(recipeService, times(1)).save(recipe, photo);
    verify(userService, times(1)).save(user);


    mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes/add"))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/recipes"))
            .andExpect(flash().attributeExists("flash"));


}


private User userBuilder() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFavorites(recipeListBuilder());
    user.setId(1L);
    user.setRoles(new String[]{"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"});
    user.setUsername("daniel");
    user.setPassword("password");

    return user;
}

private List<Recipe> recipeListBuilder() {
    List<Recipe> recipes =  new ArrayList<>();
    recipes.add(recipeBuilder(1L));
    recipes.add(recipeBuilder(2L));

    return recipes;
}

private List<Ingredient> ingredientsListBuilder() {
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    ingredients.add(ingredientBuilder());

    return ingredients;
}

private Ingredient ingredientBuilder() {
    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();
    ingredient.setCondition("good");
    ingredient.setName("test ing");
    ingredient.setQuantity(1);
    ingredient.setId(1L);

    return ingredient;
}

private Recipe recipeBuilder(Long id) {
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe.setName("Test recipe");
    recipe.setDescription("Test Description");
    recipe.setId(id);
    recipe.setCategory(Category.ALL_CATEGORIES);
    recipe.setCookTime(10);
    recipe.setPrepTime(10);
    recipe.addIngredient(ingredientBuilder());

    return recipe;
}
}
```

Comment: If you have a method which returns `void` and you want to mock the object of class that owns this method, the typical way of doing it is to verify that this method was called on mock object using `Mockito::verify`.

Comment: Also, you haven't said anything about what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Sorry I should of been more explicit. I want to mock the service call save() which takes a recipe object and a multipartfile.

Comment: Just use `Mockito::verify` to test if your logic called `save` method on your mock as you probably do not want to test the saving logic here.

Comment: I've just tried this and have received the error : "Wanted but not invoked:
recipeService.save(
    com.danielturato.recipe.recipe.Recipe@1f1574c,
    org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile@16c9e378
);
-> at com.danielturato.recipe.recipe.RecipeControllerTests.createNewRecipeRedirects(RecipeControllerTests.java:112)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock."

Comment: It means that your logic did not invoke the method. Probably `result.hasErrors()` returned true.

Comment: Or that the logic called save() on another instance of RecipeService. Show us your complete, but minimal test.

Comment: I'll add my test code now

Comment: You have to call `Mockito::verify` after the `mockMvc.perform()` ... you want to test that your request processing logic actually invoked method on your mock. `Mockito::verify` is used to assert, not to set up mocks.

Comment: There you go. You're using an **integration** Spring test, where Spring creates actual service and controllers and starts an actual web application context. So the controller and the services that it uses have nothing to do with the mock services and the controller that you create yourself in the test using the Mockito `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations. You need to use the `@MockBean` Spring annotations to tell Spring to create a mock service bean, inject it into the controller and in your test.

Comment: Even when I put the verify()'s below the peform(), I get that wanted but not invoked error. Also, what do you mean by @MockBean annotation and where would I put it

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Answer (score 2):

try `Mockito.doNothing()`: it basically tells Mockito to do nothing when a method in a mock object is called:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(recipeService).save(any(Recipe.class), any(MultipartFile.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some logic that you want to unit test and this logic invokes methods of other component that you want to mock and some of those methods return `void` - the typical way of testing your logic is to verify that your logic actually invoked the `void` methods of mocked object. You can achieve this by using `Mockito::verify` :

```
 Mockito.verify(recipeService, Mockito.times(1)).save(any(Recipe.class), any(MultipartFile.class));
```

This way you test that logic of `persistRecipe()` method actually invoked the desired method on your mock object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mocking the save method I would use one of the ‘do...‘
[Docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs)
Of course this suggests your method has a side effect somewhere.

If you want to ensure a method is called the you can use ‘verify‘ as mentioned in other answers.

Generally speaking mocking allows you to replace some collaboration/functionality with a version which is under the tests control where as verifying allows for checking something occurred (or didn’t)